# Using Koala, how can I attach an image when I publish to a user's stream?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, facebook, koala

I've started to play with the Koala gem for a RoR app. I've already got permission from the user to publish to their stream

After this line

```
graph = Koala::Facebook::GraphAPI.new(@facebook_cookies["access_token"])
```

to post to the stream, I can do a

```
graph.put_object("me", "feed", "I am writing to my wall")
```

The above works, but how do I include an image like http://example.com/foo.jpg as part of the update? I tried reading up the Stream Attachments but without a lot of luck. Does anyone have some sample code?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use something like:

```
options = {
  :message => "I am writing to my wall",
  :picture => "http://example.com/foo.jpg"
}
graph.put_object(facebook_uid, "feed", options)
```